# Connecting to a MongoDB with Android in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, mongodb, mongodb-java

I am currently developing an Android application, which is going to use a database from `MongoLab`. Another member of my team has already created a working database on `mongolab.com`, I am just having trouble connecting to it via Eclipse.

I have looked all around Google and at countless tutorials, but I really don't know much about what I'm doing.

The best tutorial I have found is from [`mkyong.com`](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-mongodb-tutorials/). It seems the second section labeled `Java MongoDB Examples` is what I am looking for, but I cannot get the library being used in those examples imported into my projects.

Is there a URL I can search for in **Help >> Install New Software** in Eclipse? I have downloaded the `mongo-java-driver`, but do not know how to incorporate that into my Eclipse.

To clarify again, I have no need to create a `MongoDB`, I am just trying to connect to an existing database via an Android project in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You must add the driver jar to your CLASSPATH, please refer to this [FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_an_extra_library_to_my_project%27s_classpath%3F).

If you have done this correctly Eclipse should be able to provide import for the the Mongo class if you type something like:

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the rest API provided by the Mongo Lab , not the java API. Send Http call to the server and get the response and parse it using JSON Parsor, that should do it.

Comment: Why would you say that (use the REST API, not the Java)? Really I'm curious - current Java drivers are said to be Android compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Java Mongo driver 2.6 is compatible with Android.

The actual version 3.0.3 isn't compatible with Android because javax.security.sasl.* isn't implemented on Android.

I'm working on a forked version of 3.0.3 adding javax.security.sasl classes of this project https://github.com/koterpillar/android-sasl